# Is it safe to keep all of our php functions in 1 files and then include it in all the other files?

Tags: php, security, include

I am creating a PHP website and it contains several sections, I was wondering is it safe to keep all of my functions in 1 file and then **include it in every other file**?

It would certainly make things easier for me but do you think it's a good idea? In both **security** aspects and **speed**. Because if I keep all my functions in a single page it would definitely become quite big, and I wouldn't be needing a lot of them in a lot of pages, so, wouldn't it affect my script's speed?

And do you think it's wise to keep all of them together? Aren't I just making it easier for hackers to find the core of my script? What do you suggest I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big, long functions files were (and still are, to an extent) pretty common in PHP projects.

Security of all files should certainly be a consideration, but a single functions file is no different from any other, really. Best practice is to keep it outside of your web root so that if PHP fails (it happens), your file still won't be accessible. If the server gets hacked, the location and format of your files is unlikely to make any difference.

Modern frameworks typically include hundreds of different files on every page load. The extra time this takes is barely measurable and probably not worth thinking about.

For maintainability, it's rarely a good idea to have one massive file. You should look at separating these into utility classes and autoload them as needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It was very helpful, and also make a lot of sense , i'll try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Security-wise, it is safe as long as the file is kept under the right permissions.

It is not the best practice, and I guess you should take a look at php's [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Answer (score 0):

Security has **nothing** to do with the **size** of file.
You just need to make it **inaccessible** (which you can do it by .htaccess) and **hidden** by public (keep it outside of the web root)

And, what about the speed ?
I think it's nicer to get the files organized **as specific as possible**.
If there are many of tiny functions, you can organized it by its shared characteristics (maybe string functions, array functions, etc)
The time overhead is very very small and can be **negligible**.
And, I think **maintainability** is much more **important** than that **negligible** performance difference.

Comment: Thank you very much. For your time and your insightful answer.